# How to add text in a created table in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I created a table in `RichTextBox` like this:

```cs
//Since too much string appending go for string builder
StringBuilder tableRtf = new StringBuilder();

//beginning of rich text format,dont customize this begining line              
tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1 ");

//create 5 rows with 3 cells each
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    tableRtf.Append(@"\trowd");

    //A cell with width 1000.
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx1000");

    //Another cell with width 2000.end point is 3000 (which is 1000+2000).
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx2000");

    //Another cell with width 1000.end point is 4000 (which is 3000+1000)
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx3000");

    //Another cell with width 1000.end point is 4000 (which is 3000+1000)
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx4000");

    tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl \cell \row"); //create row
}
tableRtf.Append(@"\pard");
tableRtf.Append(@"}");
this.misc_tb.Rtf = tableRtf.ToString();
```

Now I want to know how I can put text in headers and in each cells.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert text dynamically, you should declare DataTable, for example:
DataTable dt and you can change data dynamically with dt. After changing each time you should render to tableRtf and set to misc_tb.Rtf that tableRtf.
In othe way, you should define cell location (with like IndexOf method) and insert text that location.

**Updated:**
maybe theese links are will help you:

http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/netrtfwriter/netrtfwriter/latest%20-%200.9.1/RtfWriter_V0.9.1.zip

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C

in RtfTable class has cell(int row, int col) method, sure it will help

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that with indexof please ?

Answer (score 0):

Add AppendLine in Your Code to add text.
I hope it will work

```
tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx1000").AppendLine(" ID");       
tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx2000").AppendLine(" First Name");         
tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx3000").AppendLine(" Lastname");       
tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx4000").AppendLine(" Salary");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your text in last line in the loop, that is:

```
tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl \cell \row");
```

In mentioned example, you have 3 cell in each row. So, you should put your text between \intbl and \row. For example:

```
tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl  MyText1 \cell  MyText2 \cell  MyText3 \cell \row");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can populate cells with hard coded data as below 3 rows are populated with data:

```
      tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl   1" + @"\cell    Raj" + @"\cell    Bangalore" + @"\cell    India" + @"\row");
      tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl   2" + @"\cell    Peter" + @"\cell    Mumbai" + @"\cell   India" + @"\row");
      tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl   3" + @"\cell    Chris" + @"\cell    Delhi"+ @"\cell   India" + @"\row");
```

Also can Insert DataTable data to RichTextBox table in loop ,for these samples see the link [Add text in a created table in a richtextbox](http://www.dotnetstuffs.com/how-to-add-text-in-a-created-table-in-a-richtextbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Plus data in row

```cs
StringBuilder tableRtf = new StringBuilder();
tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}");
for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
{
    tableRtf.Append(@"\trowd");
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx2500" + "  " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["caption"].ToString());
    tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl\cell");
    tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx10000\intbl\cel");
    tableRtf.Append("   " + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[k][j].ToString() + @"\intbl\clmrg\cell\row");
}
tableRtf.Append(@"\pard");
tableRtf.Append(@"}");
richTextBox2.Rtf = tableRtf.ToString();
```